# Prolog DCG read from file with separotr

Tags: prolog, dcg

I'm making my first steps in Prolog, but I have encountered a problem.

I'm trying to read from a file records separated by comma

```
upto_comma(Codes) --> string(Codes), ",", !.
list_w([W|Ws]) --> upto_comma(W), [W] ,list_w(Ws).
string([]) -->  [].
string([H|T]) -->[H],string(T).
```

but all I got is a list with the single characters, while what I wanted is a list of element. For example from

```
cat,dog,table
```

I want `[cat,dog,table]` and I got `[c,a,t,d,o,g,t,a,b,l,e]`.

I have tried to change `upto_comma` in

```
upto_comma(Atom) --> string(Codes), ",", !,{ atom_codes(Atom, Codes) }.
```

but nothing changed.

I think there's some basic concept I misunderstood, anybody can help?
I'm using SWIProlog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your grammar misses the base case of list_w//1, and I can't understand why after upto_comma(W) you require the same thing just read.

I would write this way

```
list_w([W|Ws]) --> string(W), ",", !, list_w(Ws).
list_w([W]) --> string(W).

string([]) -->  [].
string([H|T]) -->[H],string(T).
```

test:

```
?- phrase(list_w(S),"cat,dog").
S = [[99, 97, 116], [100, 111, 103]] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting; I don't get that result from the code you show; I just get a failure to parse the input.

First, think about what your `string` rule recognizes.  Does it recognize any string of characters? Or only strings of characters that don't have a comma?

Then think about how the list_w terminates.  What code handles the case of the final "table" in your input?  It can't be upto_comma, because that requires that "table" be followed by a comma.  And list_w doesn't have any right hand side that doesn't include upto_comma.